# How can I downgrade the Xamarin.ios version Visual Studio 2019 make compatible with Xcode 10.2

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2019

When I updated the Visual Studio it shows me to update the Xcode 10.2 to 11 to make xamarin.ios compatible with it. So planned to downgrade the xamarin.ios Visual Studio in my Windows machine. How to downgrade Xamarin.ios in Windows machine?

Comment: Unfortunately there’s no way to downgrade the Xamarin.iOS SDK version since each Visual Studio version requires a specific version of Xamarin.iOS.You can download the VS with old version . However ,  I don't suggest you to downgrade the version of Xamarin.iOS .

Comment: It was possible to downgrade my Xamarin.ios in my MAC machine.In my mac machine, i am using VisualStudio 2019 with xamarin.ios for xcode 10.2. Unfortunately when I try with remote pairing from my window machine its not working.

Comment: But on window you could not implement it .You can download an old version VS .